# .push_back() alternatve in C?

Tags: c, function, vector

Is there a C function equivalent to C++'s .push_back() and if not, how can I create my own in C? I did research and attempted to write my own but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Never going to happen. Dynamic arrays are way outside the scope of C's design philosophy. Look for a library like [`apr`](https://apr.apache.org). Don't write your own unless you like re-re-re-reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Do you have any library recommendations?

Comment: Searching for "c dynamic array library" returns an *embarrassment* of riches.

Comment: https://docs.gtk.org/glib/

Answer (score 1):

In C we use `realloc()` to resize a dynamically allocated array.

You probably need a struct to hold `capacity` and `size`.  `std::vector` has template parameters for both type and allocator.  In C you either go the `void *` route or write a macro to generate implementations that are type safe.  The allocator, which in C would be a function pointer, would determine how to grow or shrink capacity (say, a factor of current size, or a 4k block at a time).

push_back may move a value, someone correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think C has a concept for that.  It may, however, be a compiler optimization.  `push_back()` may throw an exception so error handling would have to be different in C.

Comment: That's 5% of the way there.

Comment: @tadman Not really sure how to parse that.  As in arrays are not containers?  Or buffer management?

Comment: @tadman, No, it is not wasteful to resize on each single append operation. In worst case scenarios (gigabyte arrays, single char append/write), the single char resize/write was about twice the time than doubling the buffer on each resize. In a real world scenario where you have to do real work to read and process the data, the allocation time would probably not matter. (tests was done on GNU/Linux on a recently new libc a few years ago).

Comment: @HAL9000 It has to allocate and potentially move the data. I'm highly suspicious that this has no impact on large allocations.

Comment: @tadman if enough space is reserved already, `realloc` will just update some bookkeeping. Over-allocation strategies are a consideration for `realloc` as they are for `std::vector` implementors.

Comment: @tadman, I havn't looked at the innards of `malloc`, but there a few ways this can be optimized. 1. `reaalloc` can detect that the memory following your buffer is unused, and just increment the reserved area. 2. `realloc` can do doubling of the buffer size behind the scenes.  It is worth noting that even Stroustrup claimed the the best way to create and initialize a container, was to use `std::vector` and use single `.push_back` (this was before we got `.emplace_back`)

Comment: @M.M While I know some implementations do that, there are some pretty *awful* implementations out there. I'd argue I'd trust any modern standards compliant `std::vector` to do the right thing a lot more than I would some random C `malloc()`.

Comment: @HAL9000 *the single char resize/write was about twice the time than doubling the buffer on each resize. In a real world scenario where you have to do real work to read and process the data, the allocation time would probably not matter. (tests was done on GNU/Linux on a recently new libc a few years ago).*  Now do that test with 8-16 threads doing 1-`char` reallocations simultaneously.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I might do it, but as far as I know, modern `malloc`s are "almost" lock-free, so I don't see how `realloc` in one thread will affect other threads. And if `realloc` does buffer-size doubling behind the scenes, that would not be any different than manually doing it.